# How to remove long hash for Rails App in Heroku and Papertrailapp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, papertrail-app

I have a Rails 5 app in Heroku, and set up a Papertrailapp account to check the logs easier than checking manually in the console via `heroku logs -t`. And I'm loving it. But I feel there's too much noise.

Before I used to activate Rails-12-factor gem to be able to see SQL logs in Heroku, but now [they say](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-5) from Rails 5 and up it's not needed anymore. So now I see the SQL w/out problem, but it's longer than before.

```
Feb 24 20:38:59 myapp-staging app/web.1:  I, [2017-02-25T01:38:59.133806 #4]  INFO -- : [b2be3dbb-edb6-45f7-8686-d37304ad3782]   Rendered shared_partials/_head.html.slim (0.8ms)
```

That's a sample of a common line of log I see in Papertrail, so I'd like to understant some parts of it, and get an idea on how to disable some of those parts.

```
Feb 24 20:38:59                                   # Papertrail DateTime
myapp-staging                                     # Papertrail system
app/web.1:                                        # Heroku Dyno
I,                                                # I guess this comes from the "new" Rails-12-factor way of logging, INFO, DEBUG, and so on
[2017-02-25T01:38:59.133806 #4]                   # I guess it's the DateTime from Heroku server
INFO -- :                                         # Again, the type of log, but whole word. Rails generated?
[b2be3dbb-edb6-45f7-8686-d37304ad3782]            # This is a hash that IDK where it comes from, nor what it means and what is used for
Rendered shared_partials/_head.html.slim (0.8ms)  # The actual log message of Rails app
```

So I guess my questions are:

- What is that hash, and how is that useful? How to remove it from the logs?
- How do I remove the DateTime from Rails Logs (given that Papertrailapp is already giving me that info) (what bad consequences could that bring?)
- How to remove the `I,` part, that is already in the `INFO --`

### Update 26-02

Thanks to the @slothbear answer, I0've checked manually the logs form the console `heroku logs -t` and I've noticed the Papertrail Datetime seems to be actually a reformat from [Heroku DateTime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-format) because a regular message looks like this:

```
2017-02-26T18:00:09.976118+00:00                      # Heroku Datetime
app[web.1]:                                           # Heroku source[dyno]
I,                                                    # Type of log
[2017-02-26T18:00:09.976009 #4]                       # Rails Datetime
INFO -- :                                             # Again type of log
[a6612ea9-1a31-46d3-8c8d-7f93f971c379]                # Request ID
Rendered shared_partials/_top_card.html.slim (3.5ms)  # Actual Rails message
```

So, knowing that Heroku DateTime would be more difficult to remove, I think I'll remove Rails DateTime, and may be RequestID too.

Comment: Take a look at the `Logger::Formatter#call` method source to see where most of the Rails message is coming from. The long hash is added by Rails TaggedLogging. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/Formatter.html#method-i-call

Comment: Based on Heroku's description of their [Log format](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-format), it looks like what you label as _Papertrail DateTime_ may be a reformatted version of the full Heroku _Timestamp_.

Comment: I was exactly in this moment checking on that, I think you're right, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long hash is the `request_id`. This ID allows you to track a single request in the log. You can remove the ID by editing `config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]`

The DateTime format can be set to something short in `production.rb`, though some characters remain:

`config.log_formatter.datetime_format = ""`

For more control of the message after the [Heroku-standard parts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-format) (as interpreted by Papertrail) you need a custom log formatter. The production default is  [Logger::Formatter](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/Formatter.html), as described in the [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) guide. You can replace the default logger in `production.rb`:

```
# config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

class UnmultiFormatter < ::Logger::Formatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "unmultilog [#{severity}]: #{msg}\n"
  end
end

config.log_formatter = UnmultiFormatter.new
```

Note that this custom formatter gets wrapped by `TaggedLogging` if the `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` environment variable is set — which is set by default on Heroku.

Bad consequences of removing items? When debugging complex issues, more information is always better – and the default log information has been devised by a lot of smart folks. If you're working with a simpler app you're probably ok. Ideally, the log viewer would let you turn off items as you like – and turn them back on if debugging requires them. Papertrail does some of this: click on **Options** at the bottom of the screen and you can turn off time, app, and program name.

Comment: Thanks this is a very useful and clear answer. I think then when turning off system, program and DateTime, the system is the only Papertrail piece of info, because DateTime and program comes form Heroku.

Comment: Hi quick question, how do I test removing DateTime in development if I can't see the date on local development messages?, even copying the settings from `production.rb`?

Comment: The development environment is the default when you start a server locally, but you can run the production environment: `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` . You may need to fill in a couple of gaps (like creating a production database and SECRET_KEY_BASE) that Heroku does for you automatically... let the error messages guide you.

Comment: In the development environment, Rails uses the very simple `ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter` as documented in this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Comment: I have no idea why I couldn't get the formatter working before. When I add the custom `log_formatter` to a new Heroku app now, it works fine. I've included sample code in the answer.